# Unix CAN socket does not wait for message

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, unix, can-bus

I have a unix CAN socket created as below:

```
#include <linux/can.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {

    struct can_frame _msg;

    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    int _sock_fd = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);

    if (_sock_fd < 0) {
    }

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "can0");
    if (0 != ioctl(_sock_fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr)) {
    }
    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

    fcntl(_sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    if (0 != bind(_sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))) {
    }

    while (1) {
      ssize_t size = 0;
      ssize_t tmp = 0;
      while (size < sizeof(struct can_frame)) {
        tmp = read(_sock_fd, &_msg, sizeof(struct can_frame));
        if (tmp <= 0) {
            printf("0\n");
        }
        size += tmp;
    }
    printf("%x %x %lx\n", _msg.can_id, _msg.can_dlc, *((uint64_t*)_msg.data));

  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I do `read` on this socket, i always get message immediately even if sender does not send anything. `read` always read duplicate of latest recieved message instead of waiting for next. I perform reading as below:

```
    size_t size = 0;
    while (size < sizeof(struct can_frame)) size += read(_sock_fd, &_msg, sizeof(struct can_frame));
```

It is confusing for me, why read always returns duplicated message intead of waiting for next one. If I call read function in loop with `yeld`, it spawns millions of duplicates of same message when sender sent just one: `candump` utility shows received messages right way. Why does it have this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure the sender sends the message only once and does not repeat the message with the same data in a certain interval? How did you check this? Please [edit] your question and add all information there.

Comment: Instead of doing a calculation with the return value of `read`, check the value first. (What would happen if `read` returns -1 to indicatge an error.) Maybe the `read` returns 0 because you have set `O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you compile use C++, not C. They have different rules for union type punning and `ifr.ifr_ifindex` is a union member. As a rule of thumb, always establish which programming language you are going to use before you start writing the code.

Comment: @Bodo, Updated, I use `candump` for see network traffic and it show frames okay

Comment: @Bodo, i changed code for handle zero and error return of read, but it always successfully reads the same frames

Comment: @Lundin, I updated example for be able compile same code as C and as C++ and both variants works the same bad.

Comment: @Bodo, disabling blocking mode fixed situation, thanks

Comment: Did you try the code from the question? The `while(1)` loop will never terminate, so it will never reach the `printf`. It doesn't make sense to add the return value of read to `size` until you reach the full size and not adjust the pointer where to store the data for the `read`. This looks like a broken attempt to handle partial reads. (I don't know if partial reads are possible with socketcan.) I suggest to zero-fill `_msg` at the same place where you set `size_t size = 0;` The return type of `read` is **`ssize_t`** (signed), not `size_t` (unsigned). `size_t` can never be `< 0`.

Comment: @Shadasviar with "disabling blocking mode" you probably mean "disabling **non**-blocking mode. If this fixed your problem, this is an indication that you have a bug in your handling of non-blocking `read`s.

Comment: @Bodo, code from example is working, but its read errors handling is really  buggy, thanks for attention.

Comment: @Shadasviar It depends on what you understand as "is working". Your `while(1)` loop will never terminate and your program will never reach the `printf("%x %x %lx\n",`...

Comment: @Bodo, I meant that it show repeated frames with infinity speed as in question asked. I wrote this code without attention for reproduce my issue so it is buggy with types mismatching. But it really return zero most of time with non blocking mode, thanks

Comment: @Bodo, program will reach this printf succesfully, why it should not? It will never reach printf with zero

Comment: You are right, your code indentation is misleading.

Comment: If you found the answer to your problem it would be nice if you wrote a self-answer (that's possible and encouraged) as a reference for posterity. Show the code providing a solution in the answer.

Comment: @Bodo, you are welcome for post your answer and get scores for it :)